# BLAZOR WEBASSEMPLY and MYSQL WORKBRENCH - DbContext problem

Tags: blazor, dbcontext, mysql-connector

I am using Mysql Workbench to connect in our server, how to use it in Blazor? What is this error?

Win32Exception: The parameter is incorrect.

SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

AppDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AselWebAppV3.Shared.Models;

namespace AselWebAppV3.Server
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Defect> defects { get; set; }

      
    }
}
```

STARTUP.CS

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Linq;

namespace AselWebAppV3.Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit       https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=10.111.*.****,3307; uid=sa; Password=*******; Database=****; Integrated Security=True;"));
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
           
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.U

seExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

TRY TO CONNECT THE SERVER`

Comment: InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error.


Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryProcessHeader()
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(bool encrypt, bool trustServerCert, bool integratedSecurity, out bool marsCapable, out bool fedAuthRequired)
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, bool ignoreSniOpenTimeout, long timerExpire, bool encrypt, bool trustServerCert, bool integratedSecurity, bool withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType)

Comment: Mysql workbench is for mysql, but your code tries to connect to ms sql server, which is a completely different database product.

Answer (score -1):

Try add `trustservercertificate=true` to your connection string since the error says trustServercert

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Connection": "Server=localhost;User Id=admin;Password=****;Database=****;
    Trusted_Connection=True;
    TrustServerCertificate=True;"  
},
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried but same error

Comment: is 3307 port or 3306 ?

Comment: I used 3307 ...